# C# - class field is null when accessed from a worker thread but not main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, invoke, worker

Not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
class MyClass
{

    private EventInfo eventInfo;

    public void OnGenerateEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        // Called from *main* thread 

        // Load assembly and set eventInfo here
        eventInfo = ....GetEvent(...);
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(source, handler);

        // Call to a static method in another assembly
        someMethodInfo.Invoke(null, null);

    }


    public void OnEventChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {    
        // Called from a *worker* thread created 
        // by that static method in the other assembly

        eventInfo is null here !   

        // Trying to remove handler
        eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(.....);

    }


    // But...
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Called from *main* thread when program closes

        eventInfo is *not* null here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think we'd need to see reproducible code, but I can see 4 scenarios:

- you are talking to a different `MyClass` instance in the two cases - **my bet is here**
- you have a variable called `eventInfo` in one of the methods (try using `this.eventInfo` when you mean the field if there is any ambiguity)
- the write or read is cached (try marking the field `volatile`; again unlikely)
- a thread-specific field (thread-local storage) - very unlikely

The first two are much more likely.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do at least one of the following:

- make `eventInfo` volatile to ensure that `OnGenerateEvent()` writes it all the way out to memory before calling `someMethodInfo.Invoke()`
- use something like a mutex/lock to protect access to `eventInfo`. This will also provide the proper memory barriers (this is what really should be done in my opinion)

Oh, and I'm assuming that there aren't really 2 different `MyClass` instances involved - that can't be verified by the code you've shown.